# Math linear algebra age problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Travis is 66 years younger than Alicia 7 years ago Alicia's age was 3 times Travis age how old is Travis now?
What's the formula

Comment: There is a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule) (once you've written out the equations), but I doubt you want to use it :)

Comment: Why is that? Isn't that how I would figure out the answer

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Well, another way to solve it is to let $T$ and $A$ be the ages of Travis and Alicia **7 years ago** respectively. Therefore, you must solve:
$$\begin{cases} T+66=A \\ A=3T \end{cases}$$
After solving this system, just add $T$ by $7$ to get Travis' current age.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular formula for this. But you can do it this way -

Let Alicia' age be $x$ and Travis' age be $y$.

So, $y$ = $x - 66 \implies x = y+66$  .....(1)

Also, $x-7 = 3(y-7)$ 

 $\implies x-7 = 3y-21$ 

 $\implies x=3y-14$ .....(2)

So, from (1) and (2); 
$y+66 = 3y-14$

$\implies y=40$